# How to select rows that have the same value in a column, without knowing that value in advance?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of records

```
Table records(id, docId, title)
```

Given an id, I would like to select all rows equal to or less than the id, that share the same docId.  I do not know the docId in advance.

Here is some sample data:

```
insert into records (id, docId, title) values
(1, 1, 'a'),
(2, 1, 'b'),
(3, 2, 'c'),
(4, 1, 'd')
```

I can do this with two selects by doing something like so...

```
select @docId := docId from records where id = 4;

select id, title from records where docId = @docId and id <= 4;
```

...resulting in...

```
[{ id: 4, title: 'd'},{id: 2, title: 'b'},{id: 1, title: 'a'}]
```

I am wondering:  Is it possible to do this in a single query?

Comment: Please post sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join both queries:

```
SELECT id, title
FROM   records a
JOIN   records b ON a.docId = b.docId AND a.id < b.id
WHERE  b.id = 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understood your question, but if you need to search records with only one query, it may be that subselect helps you ...

```
select r.id, r.title
from records r
where r.docId in (
    select r2.docId
    from records r2
    where r2.id = 4
)
and r.id <= 4
```

I hope I've helped. Best whises.